# Add various predefined "tags" to a text field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, tags, addition

This will probably be a very easy question to answer. I am creating a form for a simple "contact manager" type php based site, with a basic data-base. I have a text field in which multiple tags can be added each profile. Currently, this is done manually. The client would like me add a predefined list of "tags" they can click on which will then add the appropriate text to that field. I was thinking I would hard code in the tags, and then use the title tag to contain the text which would be added to the field. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this, or alternate suggestions? This would be adding text to an already existing field (separated by comma, preferably the comma wouldn't be part of the text I am passing. I would like to automatically have a comma appear after each tag is added.

The alternate request was to create a series of check boxes, but I thought this might make searching the easiest. I realize this is probably super simple, but I am more of a design guy, so if anyone could point me in the right direction or provide any suggestions, it would be much appreciated. Also, I might have to have more than once instance of this on a page, so I might have to have more than one function for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addToValue(el, s) {
  if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);
  el.value += (el.value.length > 1)? ', ' + s : s;
}
</script>


<textArea id="someText"></textarea>
<button title="foo" onclick="addToValue('someText',this.title)">Add foo</button>
<button title="bar" onclick="addToValue('someText',this.title)">Add bar</button>
<button title="baz" onclick="addToValue('someText',this.title)">Add baz</button>
```